# Loading URL in uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I opens a UIwebview and from one of the sites i get some URLs, Then I save these URLs in a array, now I want to open these URL one by one in webview with some time interval. I have tried by running a for loop and loading each urls but, it is not opeing every URLs, after completion of loop it opens only the last URL in the loop.
Here is my code for the loop:

```
for(int z = 0; z<[FinalUrlArray count];  z++){
    sleep(20.0);
    NSLog(@"URLs are %@", [FinalUrlArray objectAtIndex:z]);
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[FinalUrlArray objectAtIndex:z]]]];

}
```

Can anyone suggest me if I am making some mistake or can anyone help me how can I do this.

EDIT :

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{ 
    FinalUrlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //CODE FOR creating FinalURLArray
    for(int z = 0; z<[FinalUrlArray count];  z++){
        NSLog(@"URLs are %@", [FinalUrlArray objectAtIndex:z]);
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:            [FinalUrlArray objectAtIndex:z]]]];
   }
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1 {
    NSLog(@"Current Url is %@", currentURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this loop from one of the methods like `ViewDidLoad`?

Remember the application will process your entire loop before the screen gets to be drawn so the UIWebView only gets to display the last URL. Your timer will need to operate entirely outside of the screen drawing life cycle.

What about if you create an HTML page with some JavaScript and have that iterate through the contents of the array of URLs loading them into a full page iframe?

**EDIT**

Your application will need to store the index of the current URL you are showing the same way you are already storing the `FinalUrlArray`. Load up the first URL using a method called from your `TouchUpInside` event for your button and then start the timer as suggested in the answer from @user1213334 to call the method again after an interval. Each time you will need to increment the index in the method until you get to the end. Make sure that each call to the method starts a new timer for the next load unless you reach the end.

Comment: we are having a button  and on that button press i m running this loop and taking URL from the array. So what changes in code could make it work and what about timer? where can I use that timer so that entire page gets load before a new URL starts loading.

I cant take approach where I can use HTML page and javascript, because I am doing loadtime calculations and few other things as well and for that I am using webview.

Comment: @Alok I've added some more suggestions but you may need to add more of your code if you're still stuck.

Comment: Hey Dave, I have edited my question with the button press function and DidLoadFinish. Please note that, button press is a event handler which is suppose to load the URL in webview from array to WebView. Please help.

Comment: @Alok your loop is always going to complete before any URL loading is properly completed. I would suggest you load the first URL in `buttonPressed` and then start a timer in `webViewDidFinishLoad` to wait before you then load the next URL. `webViewDidFinishLoad` should probably check if it has loaded the last URL before starting the timer. You shouldn't use `sleep` as the timer, use the proper `NSTimer` class as suggested in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because of one of these reasons:

1)you try to load these urls too fast.

2)sleep function freezes all the application. What about to use task scheduling instead of it?

**Updated**

[The original article is here](http://jonathanhui.com/ios-timer)

To schedule one task you can use something like this:

```
NSTimer *timer;
if (!myTimer) {
       myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20
                              target:self selector:@selector(doTimer:)
                              userInfo:nil
                              repeats:YES];
   }
```

where "doTimer:" is a function:

```
- (void)doTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
```

To schedule a lot of tasks you can also try to schedule tasks with various intervals which are increasing in a loop. It allows to set 20 seconds interval between beginnings of two tasks.
If you need to implement the same code you wrote without changes then I advice you to write "repeats:NO" and schedule another task at the end of the previous one. It allows to make a 20 seconds interval between the ending of one task and beginning of another task.

Comment: URLs should not get loaded fast, thats y I am using sleep. I dont knw if it will still load URLs fast. Scheduling the tast in xcode! can you please help me with some example.

Comment: i have edited my post to help you. But I don't suppose that task scheduling is much better than sleep function

Comment: I will try this out and will get back to u. Thanks a lot. :)